# Gradle sync error : "failed to resolve:SMSSDK-3.0.0"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just want to place the SMSSDK in my module's build.gradle file. But, After adding it to the file and then when I try to sync it gives me an error,I don't know how to rectify this error.I hope someone who can tell me what this error is. I'm using android studio 3.0.0

the follow code was i added in the module build.gradle

```
repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation name:'SMSSDK-3.0.0',ext:'arr'
    implementation name:'SMSSDKGUI-3.0.0',ext:'arr'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

[image: link]

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo in your build script. You tell it to use the `arr` file, while those are `aar` files.